# How to set width for date filter on kendo grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid with filter row as this examble:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-row

Because my grid have many columns, so i must to set width of input filter, i used filterable template to do that:

```
{ 
    field: "CustomerName",
    title: "CustomerName",
    filterable: { 
        cell: { 
            template: function (input) { 
                input.width("60%"); 
                input.keydown(preventPost); 
            }
        }
    }
},
```

And on date columns:

```
{
    field: "DueDate", 
    title: "Modified", 
    format: "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", 
    filterable: { 
        cell: { 
            template: function (input) { 
                input.width("60%"); 
                input.keydown(preventPost);
            }
        }
    }
},
```

It ok with number and string columns, but date columns occur problem.

Before i set width for columns, it show datepicker on date columns.

After i set width for columns, it show textbox on date columns.

So how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply define the width of the column and let Kendo UI compute it.

```
{
    field: "OrderDate",
    title: "Order Date",
    format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
    width: 150
}
```

Check the following code that is the example that you refer to in your post.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      type: "odata",
      transport: {
        read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
      },
      schema: {
        model: {
          fields: {
            OrderID: { type: "number" },
            Freight: { type: "number" },
            ShipName: { type: "string" },
            OrderDate: { type: "date" },
            ShipCity: { type: "string" }
          }
        }
      },
      pageSize: 20,
      serverPaging: true,
      serverFiltering: true,
    },
    height: 550,
    filterable: {
      mode: "row"
    },
    pageable: true,
    columns: 
    [
      {
        field: "OrderID",
        width: 125,
        filterable: {
          cell: {
            showOperators: false
          }
        }
      },
      {
        field: "ShipName",
        width: 200,
        title: "Ship Name",
        filterable: {
          cell: {
            operator: "contains"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        field: "Freight",
        width: 255,
        filterable: {
          cell: {
            operator: "gte"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        field: "OrderDate",
        title: "Order Date",
        format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
        width: 180
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```css
html { 
  font-size: 12px; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: I used Kendo UI version v2014.2.716, so it not working when i modify my grid the same your way.

Comment: What about moving to the newer version of Kendo UI? Seems to be something that they already fixed...

Comment: I really want to use the newest version of Kendo UI, but unfortunately, my company has no plans to upgrade. so i need to try another way ....